# Change columns order by dates

Tags: excel, vb.net, vba

I have several columns, each has first cell with an Excel date serial number (ex. 42767 which is equal to 2017-02-01). I have to reorder all columns ascending by those dates.

Comment: have you tried the sort button on the Data ribbon? Or do you want to do this programmatically?

Comment: using vba, posted an answer below (I managed to record macro)

Answer (score 0):

NVM, posting an answer to my own question:

```
Range("B1").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("B1:C1") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Arkusz1").Sort
    .SetRange Range("B1:C8")
    .Header = xlGuess
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlLeftToRight
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```